# Detect via javascript whether Silverlight is installed

Tags: javascript, silverlight

Is there a javascript function I can use to detect whether a specific silverlight version is installed in the current browser?

I'm particularly interested in the Silverlight 2 Beta 2 version. I don't want to use the default method of having an image behind the silverlight control which is just shown if the Silverlight plugin doesn't load.

**Edit:** From link provided in accepted answer:

Include Silverlight.js (from Silverlight SDK)

```
Silverlight.isInstalled("2.0");
```

Comment: Note that you need to specify the minor version (".0"). Trying `Silverlight.isInstalled("2")` works in Firefox, but doesn't work in IE.

Comment: @Husky there is no reason not to put the `.0` in, as it will make it work in IE and any silverlight sub versions installed on the clients machine like `.1` will still return true when testing for `.0`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Include Silverlight.js (from Silverlight SDK)

`Silverlight.isInstalled("4.0")`

---

**Resource:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265155(vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 9):

Please actually use the latest script available at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlightjs for the latest updates.  This has several fixes in it.

Comment: That is no longer the latest and, in fact, has "been retired."

Comment: @JoeMabel any chance you know where a script could be found that's not retired?

Comment: Afraid not. I don't know what would be the preferred way to do this now.

Answer (score 0):

```
var hasSilverlight = Boolean(window.Silverlight);

var hasSilverlight2 = hasSilverlight && Silverlight.isInstalled('2.0');
```

Etc....

Comment: `Boolean(window.Silverlight)` merely checks for the presence of the Javascript library on the page, not the Silverlight plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Download this script: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlightjs

And then you can use it like so:

`if (Silverlight.isInstalled)
{
alert ("Congrats. Your web browser is enabled with Silverlight Runtime");
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (Silverlight.isInstalled("1.0")) {
            try {
                alert("Silverlight Version 1.0 or above is installed");
            }
            catch (err) {
                alert(err.Description);
            }
        }
        else {
            alert("No Silverlight is installed");
        }
```

from this [video](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/all/how-to-determine-if-silverlight-is-installed/).

Silverlight.isInstalled is always true so version string such as "1.0" must be provided to make it useful.

Comment: «Silverlight.isInstalled is always true» This is not correct. I don't use Silverlight, but on a website which includes the SDK, `Silverlight.isInstalled()` correctly returns `false`.