# Integrating Silverlight 'views' into an ASP.MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, authentication, view, biometrics

We have developed a Silverlight Control which performs some biometric's to establish someone's identity and will be using it to authenicate a user in our MVC app.

However we want to provide for someone which does not have Silverlight installed and therefore return a view which provides a normal login/password type stuff.

My question is :

What's the best way to control which control to display; should the controller make the decision about which view to use depending on detecting silverlight or should a single view make a decision about what to display.

Any advice / best practice would be gratefully recieved.

Answer (score 0):

You could detect if Silverlight is installed using JavaScript and redirect them (window.location = '/signin') to the sign in page if they don't have it installed.

[Detect if Silverlight Installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119980/detect-via-javascript-whether-silverlight-is-installed)

[How to: Add Silverlight to a Web Page by Using JavaScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265155%28VS.95%29.aspx)