# Is there a way to test if a browser supports flash/silverlight?

Tags: iphone, ajax, silverlight, flash, ipad

I'm making an application with SL/flash charts and am wondering if there is a way to test if the browser it's being pushed to supports silverlight or not (ipad/iphone). And if it doesn't, then I can use some kind of AJAX chart in its place.

If this is possible to interchange platforms by testing against the host, how would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For flash, you can either use this: http://ppk.home.xs4all.nl/js/flash.html or this: http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/how/shock/javaplugs/javaplugs04.html

Silverlight is discussed here: [Detect via javascript whether Silverlight is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119980/detect-via-javascript-whether-silverlight-is-installed)

Comment: The Flash detection script in the link above (the adobe.com one) is very old, it mentions Flash 3 and Macromedia (Flash 4 was released in 1999 and Macromedia was acquired by Adobe in 2005). Unless I misunderstand something in this question and answer, I would recommend using SWFObject instead, it's more or less a de facto standard for Flash detection, http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

Comment: You're right. It is old but i didn't know exactly what he needs to i also added this link. The first link will work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use little hack here.

Make simple as3 flash movie and make call

```
        try
        {
            navigateToURL(new URLRequest("javascript:flashCheck()"),"_self");
        }
        catch (e:Error){}
```

and after that you can write simple check function in javascript ( flashCheck(){} ).

You know that this function only callable from as3 (swf) so you can determine what you need to.

Hope this helps.

p.s.

and i pretty sure that you can do this trick with you silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

We've use this in the past,
http://developer.apple.com/internet/webcontent/detectplugins.html

Doesn't do Silverlight.