# Browser feature detection - Is Silverlight supported?

Tags: javascript, silverlight, browser-feature-detection

I'm a keen advocate of feature detection opposed to device detection.  I'd like to be able to detect whether a browser (mobile or otherwise) supports Silverlight.

I've had a good google and found this [Silverlight supported user agent](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SLsupportedUA) but looking at the last comment it does not seem to be up to date.

There is also this SO question [Is there a way to test if a browser supports flash/silverlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320562/is-there-a-way-to-test-if-a-browser-supports-flash-silverlight) But it doesn't seem to answer the question.  Detecting if Silverlight is installed is different to detecting support for Silverlight.

Does anyone have any experience on this and whether it is possible?

Comment: I think the answer for mobile devices can be hardcoded as `return false;` :-)

Comment: Silverlight is not a "browser feature", it's a plugin. You'll need to find out how each browse exposes this information to JavaScript (if it all).

Comment: Yes that is a good point @MattHolmes, it is a plugin which may make it difficult to detect support for.

Answer (score 1):

> Detecting if Silverlight is installed is different to detecting support for Silverlight.

It is indeed different. Opera is not "supported" but runs Silverlight just fine :)

Use `Silverlight.isInstalled` in `Silverlight.js` to check if Silverlight is installed (see: http://developer.yahoo.com/dotnet/silverlight/embedding.html). Is there any reason that isn't sufficient for you?

If you must create a database of which browsers are compatible with Silverlight, then I suggest leveraging crossbrowsertesting.com

Comment: If I use `isInstalled` isn't that going to give me incorrect results in terms of support? If a browser doesn't have support for Silverlight I need to display a different experience for the user.

Comment: @ColinBacon I don't see why you do. Just tell them to install Silverlight AND/OR use a browser that supports it (don't even list them, as the list will change). Maybe if you detect Linux or a mobile OS (which definitely don't support Silverlight and never will), then tell them to use a supported OS. If you have a javascript fallback, then mention it in all cases. Don't try to be too clever. Just give the user options.