# Can we tell Edge to use IE 11 for sites for external users?

Tags: .net, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I have a publicly accessible site that various clients use. It uses Silverlight, in a .NET web app so we are stuck using it in IE11 as opposed to Edge for those users who are running Windows 10.

I've been asked to investigate whether or not we can force Edge to switch it to IE11 (or at least present the option to switch, via a link, etc.).

I've found lots of stuff on using Enterprise mode to tell Edge when it needs to run sites in IE11. However, if I am reading it all correctly, it seems this needs to be done on a per machine basis (local as opposed to server based) as it all seems geared toward internal based sites as opposed to public.

I need this same behaviour, but I need it to happen on a public site without requiring the user to jump through a bunch of hoops to set it up (as using Enterprise mode appears to require downloading tools). Even just detecting that the user is using Edge, then offer a link to open it in IE11 instead would suffice.

Is any of this possible? I don't have a Windows 10 environment to try any of this out, and won't be able to try the Microsoft VM to try it out any time soon, so I'm really just trying to figure out if it at all possible.

Comment: Edge isn't IE so "switching" isn't meaningful. You are talking about launching one browser from inside another, which isn't possible.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I haven't tried Edge yet, but I believe there is a menu option to run the site in IE11. I wasn't sure how this was implemented, so I wasn't sure if it was an option to trigger it somehow internally. I was pretty sure there wasn't, based on security issues alone, but I just wanted to confirm. So, just to confirm, there isn't any way to access that functionality, right?

Answer (score 0):

No, Microsoft Edge is a new browser from Microsoft and not just the next version of Internet Explorer. It might share some code with IE but that doesn't matter. If there was a way for HTML to force a user to change their browser then the browser wars would have played out in a very different fashion.

Your problem, however, isn't really Edge and IE but really your Silverlight requirement. Instead of detecting a specific browser you should be checking the client for your requirements and prompting them with how to meet those. For instance, I'm on Windows 10 but using Chrome without Silverlight so I couldn't use your site either.

Check out [Microsoft's Site Scan utility](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/staticscan/) that will help you find various other browser requirements that you might have.

And use the [Silverlight.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/119992/231316) file itself to perform detection *and* to check for your minimum version requirements.

```
Silverlight.isInstalled("4.0")
```

Comment: I just wasn't sure if there was some side route to get to use the "Switch to IE11" functionality (or whatever the menu item is called), or make some use of the ENterprise Mode functionality outside of an enterprise. I'm not really worried about checking for Silverlight compatibility (we already do that). I strictly want a way of using something similar to the Enterprise mode functionality without having every user jump through the significant hoops of setting it up. This said, any ideas from this point of view?

Comment: Unlike the older Compatibility Mode which both IT and web site operators could specify settings for, Enterprise Mode is only available for IT and there's no way for site operators to "hint" it. In the short term this might suck but this is better in the long term.